# What does the % mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

It's been many years since I have been in Perl and I'm finding myself needing to get back up to speed. I have a a line of code that I do not know what it means.

```
%form = %$input;
```

Can someone explain or direct me to where I can find find the answer to this?  I am not understanding the % symbol.

Comment: `%form` is a hash variable. A hash is an implementation of an associative array. See [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

Comment: `%$input`, short for `%{ $input }`, is a hash dereference (i.e. `$input` is expected to contain a reference to a hash). See [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that line copies the contents of a reference to a hash to a named hash. The programmer is likely uncomfortable with reference syntax. No big whoop.

---

The key concept that people miss about Perl 5's sigils is that they show how you are treating a variable, not what type it is. `$` is single items, `@` is multiple items. `%` is hash stuff.

The `%` signifies a hash variable *as a whole*. So, `%form` is the entire hash named "form". But, to get a single element out of it, you use the `$` (single element) sigil. When you see the `{}` after a variable, you know you are dealing with a hash:

```
%form              # entire hash named "form"
$form{foo}         # single value for key "foo" in hash form
@form{qw(foo bar)} # multiple value for keys "foo" and "bar" (slice)
```

The second one is more tricky (it's the stuff we cover in [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com). `$input` is a reference to a hash. All references are scalars (so, the `$` sigil). To use it as a hash, you have to deference it. For a simple scalar like that, you can put the hash sigil in front: %$input. Now you can treat that as a hash and use the hash operators (`keys`, `values`, `delete`) on it.

Starting with v5.26, there's also a [postfix dereference](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) so you can read your left to right: `$input->%*`.

```
%$input            # entire hash referenced by $input
$input->%*         # entire hash, with new hotness postfix deref

${$input}{foo}     # single element access: extra $ in front, braces around ref
$$input{foo}       # same thing
$input->{foo}      # single element access with arrow and braces

@{$input}{qw(foo bar)} # hash slice, multiple items get `@`
@$input{qw(foo bar)}   # same thing
$input->@{qw(foo bar)} # same thing, but with postfix notation
```

Now there's an even more tricky thing. v5.20 introduces the [key-value slice](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/07/perl-5-20-introduces-keyvalue-slices/), so the `%` gets some more work to do. This is a slice that returns the keys along with the values, so it gets the `%` for hash like things:

```
%form{qw(key1 key2)}   # returns a list of key-value pairs
```

But, this also works on arrays to get the index and value. You know it's an array because you see the `[]`, but you know it's returning index-value pairs because you see the `%`:

```
%array[1,3,7]          # returns list like ( 1, ..., 3, ..., 7, ...)
```